# QML Error- Property 'args' of object " %1" is not a function

Tags: qt, qml

I am using below piece of code in a qml file but it throws error on load.

```
        //# REQ TODO: Requirement ID from Master list of screens
        text: qsTranslate("", "Devices Found: %1").args(view.count)+ Retranslate.whenLocaleOrLangChanges
```

### Error:

### qrc:///Ravi/Screen/myExample.qml:17: TypeError: Property 'args' of object Devices Found: %1 is not a function

Can anybody help me out here? Seems, nothing is wrong here :)

Comment: Should we guess what your code is?

Comment: The intention is to update the title bar with number of of devices found. I am trying to find all available devices and displaying in a list. The list window contains a title bar and that is suppose to display a message like -> "Devices Found : <#number>". In shared code snippet, 'view.count' holds the numerical value for devices available in the list.

Comment: @RaviSGupta: So what about my answer? Not working?

Comment: @derM: Thanks derM, It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no `args()`-method.
 Maybe you meant to use the [`arg()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-string.html#arg-method)-method?